# Get current time in UTC/GMT using base R

Tags: r, datetime

I want to get current time in UTC/GMT using base R. `Sys.time()` gives me time in my local time zone. I know using `lubridate` I can do `lubridate::now(tz = 'UTC')` to get what I want but I want to do this using base R since I want to have as minimum dependency as possible.

I have tried to look around on SO for the answer but have not found any post answering my question.

One idea I had was to add/subtract number of hours my local time zone is behind/ahead of GMT respectively but I cannot use it since the code would be deployed on a server where I don't know what would be the local time zone. Also this seems to be hacky and not robust.

Is there a robust way of doing this?

Comment: May `Sys.setenv(TZ="GMT")` be you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, that can be one solution but hopefully there is also a solution where I don't have to change the global `TZ`. Can you post this as an answer @FatihAslan ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the attribute of the date/time object after you create it. For example

```
now_utc <- function() {
   now <- Sys.time()
   attr(now, "tzone") <- "UTC"
   now
}
now_utc()
# [1] "2022-08-23 13:34:36 UTC"
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the option might be:

```
Sys.setenv(TZ="GMT")
```